# How can I call two method in the same Activity that will work on the same file but in different times?

Tags: java, android, email, call, photo

I'm new to Android programming and I'm making an application that works like this: after receiving an input from SMS with some "commands" (in the form -COMMAND fileName), it reads the message's content and executes certain multimedia operations in another Activity of the App.

The problem is that when there are commands in one SMS who work on the same file (e.g. "-SHOTPHOTO photo1 -SENDPHOTO photo1") the App calls both methods to do this but only the first one is executed correctly; the other one returns an error because the photo still hasn't been taken.

```
// onCreate of the new Activity

// I received an Intent from an SMS Broadcast Receiver
// The commands and file names are saved in order in command[nCommands] and files[nFiles], nCommands and nFiles are integer and represents the number of commands/file names

for (int i = 0; i < nCommands; i++) {
    switch (command[i]) {
        case "-SHOTPHOTO":
            // finds the correct file name of this command
            shotphoto(files[j]);
            break;
        case "-SENDPHOTO":
            // finds the correct file name of this command  
            sendphoto(files[j]);
            break;
            }
}

// end of onCreate

public void shotphoto (String photoName) {
    // standard method to take photos: calls the default camera app with startActivity
    // takes photo and then renames it to photoName
    // photo saved in the ExternalStorage, in my app folder
}

public void sendphoto(String photoName) {
    // standard method to send email + photo: calls the default mail app with startActivity
    // gets the photo from my app's folder in the ExternalStorage
    // the photo is sent to the sender's mail address, which is already known
}
```

I don't have any problem when the two commands are in two different messages or when there is, for example, -SHOTPHOTO photo1 in a message and -SHOTPHOTO photo2 -SENDPHOTO photo1 in another message. I tested the reading and correctness control process and it doesn't have problems.
So I think my problem is that the two methods are executed at the same time, and sendphoto() doesn't find the photo because it hasn't been taken yet.

Some idea on how to make the two methods sinchronized, so that the first command is always executed before the second one and the second one waits for the first to finish?

I won't add a command "-SHOTNSEND photoName" cause it's not what I want. Adding sendphoto() to the end of shotphoto() won't permit me to take a photo without actually sending it.

The code I wrote here is just a very basic example of the real code, let me know if something is not clear or something really important is missing.

Comment: Instead of for, make queue with all the commands. And execute next command when the first is finished

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try it as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @X3Btel's advice to make queue and I solved my problem.
For those who want to know how I did, here's the code:

```
private Queue<String> qCommands; // global

public void onCreate(...){
    qCommands = new ArrayDeque<>();
    // read SMS' text
    qCommands.add(command[i]);     // everytime I read a command
    // same as before but without for(i->nCommands) and switch command[i]
    nextCommand(qCommands.poll());
}

public void nextCommand(String command){
    if(command != null){
        switch (command) {
            case "-SHOTPHOTO":
            // finds the correct file name of this command
            shotphoto(files[j]);
            break;
        case "-SENDPHOTO":
            // finds the correct file name of this command  
            sendphoto(files[j]);
            break;
        }
    } else {
        // the queue is empty so no more commands
}

// both shotphoto() and sendphoto() start an Activity for result so when they have finished onActivityResult will be called
public void onActivityResult(...){
    if(resultcode == SHOTPHOTO)
        nextCommand(qCommands.poll());
    if(resultcode == SENDPHOTO)
        nextCommand(qCommands.poll());
}
```

The app works and doesn't return error like before.
Thank you again, @X3Btel, for your answer!